# Work Power & Energy Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, work

If a person starts from rest with an acceleration of 10 m/s^2 and applies force of 1000N then What will be its work done at the end of 20s . If the object moves in the horizontal surface?

Can Somebody Answer me Fast.

Comment: 1.This question in highly unclear. 2.Unit of acceleration is m/s^2, not m^2. 3. If You expect help, don't insult people.

Comment: Is the acceleration an effect of the force applied? Right now it's not clearly stated in Your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the work done must be

$W=F\cdot d$

And we need to calculate just the distance, because we already have the force.

$x(t)=x_0+v_ot+\frac{1}{2}at^2=\frac{1}{2}at^2$

Finally we reemplace that in the fist equation to find the work done.

$W=F\cdot\frac{1}{2}at^2 $

Comment: Answering homework or possible live quiz questions is considered bad form here.  The "Can Somebody Answer me *Fast*" is a clue that someone is trying to get you to do their thinking for them.